# jQuery: select the first five rows of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I quickly get a jQuery selector for the textboxes in the the first 5 rows of a table? I have a table with many rows and many textboxes; I'm just trying to select the textboxes in the first 5 rows of the table. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [lt()](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt)

```
$('tr:lt(5) input[type=text]')
```

Note that it's lt(5), not lt(6), since the indexes are 0-based.

Comment: if he has more than one table, this solution doesn't discern between them

Comment: Yes this works fine. And yes jason you're correct. I would limit the scope of the selector by passing the appropriate table as the second arg to the query. thanks all. :)

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
$("#yourTable tr:lt(5) input[type=text]")
```

Answer (score -1):

see "http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild#index"

try width:

```
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(0)").html();
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(1)").html();
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(2)").html();
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(3)").html();
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(4)").html();
```